# Popup modal not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

Im working on a collage project and i want to create user signup window that popups on the click of specified text. 100% of code is pasted from https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-modal-forms/ but somehow for me  isn't working.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path("", views.check_session, name="check_session"),
path("log_in.html", views.log_in_view, name="log_in_view"),
path('registration/', views.RegistrationView.as_view(), name="registration"),
]
```

views.py

```
class RegistrationView(BSModalCreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    template_name = 'registration.html'
    success_message = 'Success: Sign up succeeded. You can now Log in.'
```

forms.py

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(PopRequestMixin, CreateUpdateAjaxMixin, UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password1', 'password2']
```

log_in.html (containing trigger of modal)

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Trading-Bot Mileva</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/log_in_style.css'%}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
</head> 
<body>
<div class="log_in_registration_bg">
    <video autoplay muted loop>
        <source src="{% static 'images_videos_sounds/log_in_registration_background.mp4' %}" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form action="log_in.html" method="POST">
        <div class="space"></div>
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="input-group mb-3 col-4">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text text-primary">Username</span>
                </div>
                {{log_in_form.username}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="input-group mb-3 col-4">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text text-primary">Password</span>
                </div>
                {{log_in_form.password}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
            {%csrf_token%}
            <input class="btn btn-outline-primary col-1" type="submit" value="Log in">
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center" id = "signup-href">
        <a href="" class="text-info ">Don't have an account? Register now</a>
    </div>
    {% if log_in_form.is_error %}
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
        <p class="error_message content">{{log_in_form.error_message}}</p>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>

<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.bootstrap.modal.forms.js' %}"></script>
<script>

        $("#signup-href").click( function(event) {
            alert("You clicked the button using JQuery!");
        });
        $(function () {
// Sign up button
            $("#signup-href").modalForm({formURL: "{% url 'registration' %}"});
        });


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

registration.html

```
<form method="post" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}

  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Sign up</h3>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">

    <div class="{% if form.non_field_errors %}invalid{% endif %} mb-2">
      {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        {{ error }}
      {% endfor %}
    </div>

    {% for field in form %}
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
        {% render_field field class="form-control" placeholder=field.label %}
        <div class="{% if field.errors %} invalid{% endif %}">
          {% for error in field.errors %}
            <p class="help-block">{{ error }}</p>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="submit-btn btn btn-primary">Sign up</button>
  </div>
</form>
```